# req.body undefined with express

Tags: node.js, express

I get a n undefined req.body on my post requests, tried everything, from body-parser through express.json, both together (sure bad) and still cannot get it to work. Any help is really appreciated!!

I have reduced my nodejs server to the minimum:

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/requests', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(201).json('all ok');
  })

app.listen(4000, () => {console.log('Server listening on port 4000')});
```

My request is (done with the REST client from VS Code):

```
POST http://localhost:4000/requests
Content-Type: 'application/json'

{
  "msg":"Some message",
  "other":"Other msg"
}
```

Comment: Additional info: I use nodejs version 12.22.9 (need it to run in an old 32bit machine) and express 14.17.2. I dont know if that could have an influence...

Comment: Here's a slightly modified instance of your example working as expected: https://runkit.com/6181458f0d176000085690c3/61fae0ca7f1c740008e41379 - using either express.bodyParser or the body-parser module makes no difference. I couldn't find any problems with what you've shown above (besides the fact that importing the express module was missing, which I charitably assumed you simply forgot to include when you put together your example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using curl, this one works here even with node `12.22.9`, pretty sure you just forgot to declare express on the top or something is wrong with your rest client

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4000/requests -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"msg":"Some message","other":"Other msg"}'
```

*.js*

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/requests', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(201).json('all ok');
  })

app.listen(4000, () => {console.log('Server listening on port 4000')});
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I guess is the settings of the REST extention for VS Code, the curl command also worked at my end!

Answer (score 0):

Just as info for other lost souls here...

If you use the REST Client app on a windows system, make sure your request has no caps. Im my case:

```
POST http://localhost:4000/requests/
content-type: application/json

{
  "msg":"Some message",
  "other":"Other msg"
}
```

AND (Also my mistake): Do not put application/json within any type of quotes, just plain!

(I did do the request from a win and a mac machine, both did not work, but it was that the reason!)